# How to implement Gradient border in CSS3 where gradient is done horizontally

Tags: css

I am trying to implement gradient border, I can do that where gradient is done vertically from top to bottom but I need to implement it from left to right, given below is my code.
Thanks in advance

```
border: 8px solid #000;
-moz-border-bottom-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-top-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-left-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
-moz-border-right-colors: #555 #666 #777 #888 #999 #aaa #bbb #ccc;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
```

Answer (score 1):

This page will show you everything you need to know (except for broken browsers like IE)

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/

And this page

http://www.westciv.com/tools/gradients/index.html

provides a graphical UI to design a gradient and generate the CSS (webkit/mozilla only, though. No support for Opera or IE).

Comment: The OP is asking about border colors, not actual CSS3 Gradients. He's creating a gradient out of multiple colors set on the border values. Having said that, I'm not sure I completely understand the question. Any example of output we can look at?

Comment: In which case, the answer is "no can do". The gradient is linear and runs from the outside towards the center. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-border-top-colors says: "the -moz-border-top-colors CSS property sets a list of colors for the top border. When an element has a border that is larger than a single CSS pixel, each line of pixels uses the next color specified in this property, from the outside in. This eliminates the need for nested boxes. If the border is wider than the number of specified colors, the remaining part of the border is the innermost color specified."

Answer (score 1):

You can fake it with multiple shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/zt2ve/